# Python regex statement errors

Tags: python, regex

I am new to using regex and would really appreciate any help here.
I have to parse a file with strings of following formats (main difference being that the second string has an extra "-" string in the middle:

1. `Abc_p123 abc_ghi_data`

   OR
2. `Abc_de*_p123 abc_ghi_data`

I could write a regex to match the first and second strings separately:

1. `data_lst = re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9]+_p\d{3})\s.*_data.*', content, re.IGNORECASE)`
2. `data_lst = re.findall('([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z]+_p\d{3})\s.*_data.*', content, re.IGNORECASE)`

Can someone guide on how to combine the two findall regex, so that it works with both strings. I can still create a combined single list by appending the second findall statement to first list. However, I am sure there is a way to handle it in one findall regex statement. I tried ".*" in the middle but, that gives error.

Please advise.
Thanks,

Comment: Are you saying that `_de*` is optional?

Comment: To match an optional part, you can use a question mark.

Comment: Yes, in some cases we have it and in other cases we don't (then it is same as string1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+\*)?_p\d{3})\s.*_data.*
```

Here is the important part:

```
(?:_[a-zA-Z]+\*)?
```

It says: optionally match an underscore, followed by unlimited a-z, followed by a asterisk.

https://regex101.com/r/5XCsPK/1

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(_[a-zA-Z]+)?_p\d{3})\s.*_data.*
```

I replaced `_[a-zA-Z]+` with `(_[a-zA-Z]+)?` to make it optional.

And if you don't want the extra capture group, add `?:` like so: `(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)?`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5xynlx/2

Comment: The pattern misses the `*` in `Abc_de*_p123 abc_ghi_data`

Comment: Nope, OP said he matches successfully the second string using `([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z]+_p\d{3})\s.*_data.*` so I think `*` meant 'any random list of letters', (which I agree was misleading, but if he really wanted to match the star, then he wouldn't say `([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z]+_p\d{3})\s.*_data.*` is working)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. In that case it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9*]+)?_p\d{3})\s.*_data
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/1jRl7D/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-zA-Z0-9*]+            any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                               'Z', '0' to '9', '*' (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _p                       '_p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{3}                    digits (0-9) (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _data                    '_data'
```